# Looking for best practice for updating an active record Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am looking for the best practice to update an active record Column.

Is using

```
User.update(current_user.id, :balance => 100)
```

Better than

```
current_user.balance=100
current_user.save
```

What about when there is a boolean?

Thank you.

Comment: No difference in matters of best practices. You choose which fits better at the moment. Don't overthink things =)

Comment: I am having trouble updating a boolean column however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `update` instance method, which doesn't require id:

```
@user = current_user

if @user.update(balance: 100, somebool: false)
  # do something if successful
else
  # do something else when failure
end
```

Comment: Would @user.update(balance: 100, somebool: false) update the balance of the user and the somebool to false?

Comment: Yes it will, and will return `true` or `false` if successful/failure